# Where to place this if statment in the php script

Tags: php

I have a php script below where it adds a database row if a new or existing file is uploaded:

```
<?php
session_start();
...//connect to DB

$result = 0;
if( file_exists("ImageFiles/".$_FILES['fileImage']['name'])) {
    $imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) 
    VALUES ('ImageFiles/".mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."')";

    mysql_query($imagesql);
} else {
    $imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) 
    VALUES ('ImageFiles/".mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."')";
    mysql_query($imagesql);
}
mysql_close();
?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>, '<?php echo $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] ?>');</script>
```

But the problem is that I want to add an if statement below the else statement when $result = 2 so that it deletes a database row. When I try this, then it doesn't insert a database row after uploading a new or existing file.

```
if ($result = 2){
  $imagecancelsql = "DELETE FROM Image 
  WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/". mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."'";
  mysql_query($imagecancelsql);
}
```

So my question is: how am I supposed to place the if statement above in the php script so that it performs its necessary database update?

Comment: It should be `if ($result == 2)`

Comment: And I don't see when $result is ever going to be 2

Comment: ^ and I don't see how accidentally setting $result = 2 affects the other if/else statement

Comment: @DaOgre result will be 2 on another page. In first page it will check to see what result is and then it navigates to this page to do whatever command depending on the number for $result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't define anywhere your $result var, so the if would never get executed. Anyway you should place it there:

```
<?php
session_start();
...//connect to DB

$result = 0;
if( file_exists("ImageFiles/".$_FILES['fileImage']['name'])) {
    $imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) 
    VALUES ('ImageFiles/".mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."')";

    mysql_query($imagesql);
} else {
    $imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) 
    VALUES ('ImageFiles/".mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."')";
    mysql_query($imagesql);
}

if ($result == 2){
  $imagecancelsql = "DELETE FROM Image 
  WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/". mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."'";
  mysql_query($imagecancelsql);
}

mysql_close();
?>
```